# Using rateYo plugin for star rating I want my stars to appear as full.

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using star rating in my project. Where my stars are appearing as the size how I hover on the star. I want stars to appear in full size while user hover on it. Any suggestion? my current JS function for rateYo is as below.

In JSP

```
      <div style="display:inline-block;" id="rateYo"></div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating_input"/>
                                </div>
```

In JS

```
       $(function () {

  $("#rateYo").rateYo({
       onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
       rating = Math.ceil(rating);
       $('#rating_input').val(rating);//setting up rating value to hidden field
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fullStar:true` option to show full star rating, Check [here](http://rateyo.fundoocode.ninja/) for official plugin options:

Update your jQuery code like this:

```
$(function () {

  $("#rateYo").rateYo({
       fullStar: true,
       onSet: function (rating, rateYoInstance) {
       rating = Math.ceil(rating);
       $('#rating_input').val(rating);//setting up rating value to hidden field
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The `fullStar:true` option makes the `rating = Math.ceil(rating);` obsolete.